# Why won't my 2002 jeep liberty move when I hit the gas?

Tags: engine, jeep, liberty

I have a 2002 jeep liberty and yesterday it started to slow down on the highway while my foot was still on the gas pedal. Today is worse.

The gas pedal makes a squeaky noise as I press down on it. The steering wheel will not turn and the car does not move when I hit the gas. It turns on, and everything works, but the car just will not go.

Is there something I can put in it to get it to work or something cause I need to move it?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You are saying your Jeep will start and idle normally, but when you put your foot on the gas pedal, it won't rev at all (which means if it's in gear, it doesn't speed the vehicle up and make it go)? It still runs if you put your foot on the brake pedal and put it in gear? No stalling? It just won't accelerate at all?

Comment: Could it be some sort of anti-theft measure? The steering wheel not turning makes me lean towards that.